# converting html to image under window service

Tags: c#, html, image, windows-services

We are trying to convert html to image using this link
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/html2image.aspx
[codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/html2image.aspx)

Under window service, and it needs to be statThread.
I have created a stat thread and waiting for the conversion, and no output or navigation to the file or site. 
One has suggested marshal, does any one have an idea hot to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: Well for the first time we used Wkhtml open source. but now we use dynamic pdf

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [How To Get A Website Thumbnail in a C# Application Without Creating A Form (console)](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Website_Thumbnails_in_C.aspx), especially the [comments where the ASP.Net case is mentionned](http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/1920451/Re-Getting-it-to-work-in-an-ASP-NET-application.aspx)

Comment: i think that my problem is the Application.DoEvent(); if this is the answer i will publish it thank you for the direction